# how to use a passed variable from sqlcmd using -v in if statement of sql script

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am working with `Microsoft SQL Server 2016` server. Assume the server's name is **ServerA** and the database's name is **DatabaseA**.

I want to write a sql script which will accept a parameter. Based on that parameter's value the sql script may execute different SQL statements.

I will be calling the sql script from `sqlcmd` passing the parameter using `-v` option.

So I wrote my SQL script `ProjectType.sql`. The parameter name is `ProjectType`. This is a basic idea of the SQL:

```
if $(ProjectType) = 'Sales'
begin
    -- my 1st set of sql statements
    select count(*) 'person_count' from person;
end
else if $(ProjectType) = 'Support'
begin
    -- my 2nd set of sql statements
    select count(*) 'employee_count' from employee;
end
```

Then I try to run using sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S ServerA -d DatabaseA -v ProjectType="Sales" -i ProjectType.sql
```

But I got error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server ServerA, Line 1
> Invalid column name 'Sales'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server ServerA, Line 6
> Invalid column name 'Sales'.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `sqlcmd` variables use dumb textual replacement, with no regards for syntax or semantics at all. It doesn't know actual T-SQL, and T-SQL doesn't know about the variables. If you want  to compare strings as strings, you have to use `if '$(ProjectType)'`, otherwise you end up with `if Sales = 'Sales'` -- and that won't work. (It also means processing values with quotes in them gets really fun, but let's assume that won't be an issue here.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks it works. Can you make your comment an answer so I can accept it?